# What lib (custom JTabbedPane) is used on this picture?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

I found a picture - java swing nimbus.[image] There they use non-standard JTabbedPane. I want such custom JTabbedPane! What lib should I use for that? Can you advise lib like that?

Comment: Take a look at [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry, I don't understand why you provide this link. I know that's nimbus. The question is how to make jtabbedpabe like on this picture.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad.  What functionality are you looking for?

Comment: It appears to be from [Just another RSDN Java offline client](https://code.google.com/p/rojac/) project, have you tried having a look?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to have JTabbedPane like this - as standard JTabbedPane is not well suitable for "like mozilla".

Comment: "like this" isn't very descriptive. The tabbed controls are easy (enough) to implement, the add is another subject...

Comment: @MadProgrammer With standard JTabbePane I have two main problems. The first one is in my quesion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393993/add-controll-jpanel-to-jtabbedpane I have only on answer and main says it's no so good solution. The second that in swing ( I use it) SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT is terrible and I need it. So I'm trying to find another implementation of tabs.

Comment: Cool, did you try the [project link](https://code.google.com/p/rojac/) that it comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nimbus is a type of look an feel in swing and you can set it as follows

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you explain how to set nimbus. I know that's nimbus and how to set it. The question is how to make jtabbedpabe like on this picture.